# Cannot create a method in a extension

Tags: flutter, dart

Just would like to create my own version of `toString` on custom type.

Seems like I'm missing something here.

```
extension on WeatherResponse { 

@override
    String toString() {
       return "City Name is: $cityName";
     }
}
```

I get the error:

```
    The method doesn't override an inherited method.
Try updating this class to match the superclass, or removing the override annotation.dartoverride_on_non_overriding_member

Extensions can't declare members with the same name as a member declared by 'Object'.

Try specifying a different name for the member.dartextension_declares_member_of_object

The declaration 'toString' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'toString'.
```

Comment: Use tostring() as lower case. The error clearly says you can't with the reason why.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Even though the class `WeatherResponse` does have a `toString` method

Comment: Exactly, there is one defined there. You can't define another one with the same name in an extension.

Comment: Thanks all, coming from Swift where this is exactly how extensions are used, so have to adjust the thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to overwrite toString method then instead of declaring it in an extension class, place it in the actual class definition. like this;

```
class YourClass extends Object {
@override
String toString() ...
}
```